# KQL result request to variable

Tags: azure, kql

I would to save the result of request in a variable for use in a new request.
But in Azure Reousrce Graph Explorer, I have an error of the syntax, but for me it's the same of the sample.
Do you have an idea ?

`let test = policyresources | where type == "microsoft.authorization/policyassignments";`

Result:
Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2022-12-27T13:41:41.4506140Z, correlationId = 9b1b87fd-27d1-4fe1-9d80-8245ce6d5802. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
More information on the error can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement

I tested my request, I tested a simple command:
`let n = 10;`

Result:
Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2022-12-27T13:46:19.0224166Z, correlationId = 665c2ca7-5568-4afd-bb72-9d2126e60544. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
More information on the error can be found here.

I think the graph explorer is bugged...

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource graph supports a subset of KQL language elements. Based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#supported-kql-language-elements), I would say `let` is not supported.

Comment: this is so confusing coming across data-explorer KQL answers on here thinking it applies to the KQL subset of Graph Explorer, thanks for clarification