# How to get a list of resource count per subscription with Azure Resource Graph Explorer query?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-resource-graph, azure-subscription

I'm trying to get a list of resource count per subscription. This is simple enough and Azure also has [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#remove-column) on how to do so. Here's my version.

```
resources
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name )
    on subscriptionId
| summarize count() by subscriptionName
| sort by count_ desc
```

What I can't figure out is how to include subscriptions with 0 resources on this table?

`resources` table only contains subscriptions that have at least one resource but it doesn't contain empty subscriptions. When I check `resourcecontainers` table, there are around 30 more subscriptions that are not showing up with the above query. These 30 subscriptions are empty.

I learned today that `let` or creating variables in Azure Resource Graph Explorer is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74930113/kql-result-request-to-variable). Otherwise, I could assign the result of the above to a variable, and do something like "resourcecontainers | where subscriptionName !in result_variable.subscriptionName" and then `union` the two results together.

My last resort is to export the results of both tables and generate what I need with Bash/PowerShell but just wanted to ask here if anybody knows how to do this here directly in Azure Resource Graph Explorer? Thanks :)

Comment: Late comment: it is highly possible that resources will not list all resources. Some of the child-resources are missing and some of the extension resources are on other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuremonitor#left-outer-join-flavor) between the resourcecontainers and the resources tables. Try this:

```sql
resourcecontainers
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
| project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name
| join kind=leftouter (resources | project subscriptionId, id) on subscriptionId
| summarize countif(isempty(id) == false) by subscriptionName
```